# Chaining dojo.connect

Tags: dojo

I have found that you cannot chain connects with consistent behavior.  In the code below, the onCustomClick method in the widget is called, but the function that is connected to it does not get called.  The workaround I have, is what I have done with onCustomClick2 where I attach the event to an internal method that simply calls the other method.  Is there a way to write this code without having to have the internal method?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Dojo Connect Issue</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="isDebug: true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["dojo/domReady!", "dojo/parser", "dijit/_Widget", "dijit/_Templated"], function(dr, p, w, t) {

        dojo.declare("W1", [w, t], {

            templateString: '<div>Click Me</div>',

            postCreate: function() {
                this.inherited(arguments);
                this.connect(this.domNode, 'onclick', this.onCustomClick);
                this.connect(this.domNode, 'onclick', this._onCustomClick2);
            },

            onCustomClick: function() {
                console.debug('onCustomClick');
            },

            _onCustomClick2: function() {
                this.onCustomClick2();
            },

            onCustomClick2: function() {
                console.debug('onCustomClick2');
            },
        });

        var w = new W1({}, dojo.byId('content'));

        dojo.connect(w, 'onCustomClick', function() {
            console.debug('End Consumer - onCustomClick'); // never gets called???
        });
        dojo.connect(w, 'onCustomClick2', function() {
            console.debug('End Consumer - onCustomClick2');
        });
        w.startup();

    }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dojo.connect works by redefining the method with a new function which calls the old one (and the method you're binding to)  So based on the order of execution here, postCreate binds to one definition of the onCustomClick method, then the dojo.connect binds to another.  Try using the connect signature that would do a lazy lookup of the onCustomClick method: (edited with Craig's correction)

`dojo.connect(this.domNode, 'onclick', this, 'onCustomClick');`

Comment: this.connect(this.domNode, 'onclick', 'onCustomClick'); is the correct syntax, this would have been needed if I was doing dojo.connect, but your explanation was right on.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're taking the wrong approach.  If all of these event handlers are being triggered by the same event, you should just have your main event handler trigger all of them:

```
postCreate: function() {
  this.inherited(arguments);
  dojo.connect(this.domNode, 'onclick', this, function(event) {
    this.onCustomClick(event);
    this._onCustomClick2(event);
  });
}
```

Also note that there is no `this.connect` provided by using `dojo.declare` to create an object, you must still use `dojo.connect`.

Alternatively, if chaining is what you really want, then try wrapping the object in a `dojo.nodeList`, which follows the builder pattern and will allow you to chain calls (I have not tested the following):

```
var w = new W1({}, dojo.byId('content'));

new dojo.NodeList(w).
  .connect('onCustomClick', dojo.hitch(w, w.onCustomClick))
  .connect('onCustomClick2', dojo.hitch(w, w.onCustomClick2));

w.startup();
```

Comment: The code I posted is a generic version of my use case.  The chaining I refer to is not onCustomClick and onCustomClick2, rather that I connect the onclick event to the onCustomClick method of the widget and then try to connect the onCustomClick method on the widget to another function outside of the widget.  The onCustomClick2 just demonstrates my workaround.  W1 extends _Widget and gets this.connect from there (via _WidgetBase).

Comment: My use case is that I have a widget that the user clicks an area of.  This widget is used in a couple places and the behavior of what should occur depends on the parent container.  So I want the parent container to connect to the method and do the appropriate functionality